# Laravel 4-pass mutiple parameters to route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel 4, and i need to know how to pass multiple parameters to `URL::route`

my route:

```
/*==========================
| edit-adherent (Get)
*///========================
Route::post('/manage-association/{id_association}/edit-adherent/{id_adherent}', array(
'as'    => 'edit-adherent',
'uses'  => 'AdherentController@postEditAdherent'
));
```

I tried the following syntax but it's not working:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('edit-adherent', $id_association, $adherent->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

I also tried that one:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('edit-adherent', array($id_association, $adherent->id)}}">Edit</a>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing the parameters as an array is actually correct, but there's a bracket `)` missing at the end in your code. So this

```
{{ URL::route('edit-adherent', array($id_association, $adherent->id)) }}
```

should workd as expected.

If you're not sure about the syntax or the right way/order to pass parameters, don't forget that Laravel is open source, so you can always have a [look at the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L197) for clarification.

If you're using an IDE like [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) or [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (both are absolutely awesome), you should check out [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper). It will show you what parameters are accepted, and if still in doubt, it will quickly lead you to the method implementation.